# pass uigesturerecognzer data to parent controller

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uigesturerecognizer

There is a master view controller with this method

```
- (void)revealGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{ 
}
```

which works when I send it a mesage froma  child viewcontroller using a swipe:

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *navigationBarPanGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self.navigationController.parentViewController action:@selector(revealGesture:)];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addGestureRecognizer:navigationBarPanGestureRecognizer];
```

I want to pass the message on from within the child viewController so I can do some house keeping first

```
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *navigationBarPanGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(revealGesture:)];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addGestureRecognizer:navigationBarPanGestureRecognizer];
```

and

```
- (void)revealGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    [displaySearch resignFirstResponder];
    RevealController *revealController = [self.navigationController.parentViewController isKindOfClass:[RevealController class]] ? (RevealController *)self.navigationController.parentViewController : nil;

    NSDictionary *data = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: recognizer, @"recognizer", nil];

    [revealController performSelector:@selector(revealGesture:) withObject:data];
}
```

Yes, all I'm trying to do is dismiss the keyboard before carrying on with a bit of code that works fine if I just target 'self.navigationController.parentViewController' directly

How do I add (UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer to the NSDictionary?

My code crashes with

```
-[__NSCFDictionary state]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8619860
2013-05-02 21:12:05.752 PwC UK[57884:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary state]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8619860'
```

EDIT Proposed solution worked but keyboard didn't respond, needed to chage the line to

```
[self searchBarCancelButtonClicked:searchBar];
```

where searchBar is instance of UISearchBar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like revealGesture is expecting a UIPanGestureRecognizer as its parameter but you are passing an NSDictionary. Try passing the gesture recognizer directly.

```
[revealController performSelector:@selector(revealGesture:) withObject: recognizer];
```

Comment: So obvious - for some reason I that withObject had to be a nsdictionary